# Android studio gives error when i add dependencies to build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-sdk-2.3

I am trying to add AdMob sdk to my android project using Android SDK.
Here is what is did.

1. i added admob jar file to the lib folder.
2. added as module
3. then added dependencies to my build.gradle.

Below is the build.gradle file looks as

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'

    }

}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
}

dependencies{
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar','libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1')
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

Below is the error.

```
Gradle 'StoriesIndian' project refresh failed:
           Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
           Build file 'C:\Users\lokesh\Desktop\MyStoryProject\StoriesIndianProject\StoriesIndian\build.gradle' line: 11
           A problem occurred evaluating project ':StoriesIndian'.
           A problem occurred evaluating project ':StoriesIndian'.
           No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.compile() is applicable for argument types: (org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection) values: [file collection]
           Possible solutions: module(java.lang.Object
```

)

Please help, what do to make it work and where to include module java.lang.object.
thanks

Comment: Love the "can't share project name", just read further :D

Comment: I think @tbruyelle point is your Project name is clearly visible. I'm not sure if this could be the issue but you can combine both `dependencies` into a single child.

Comment: `GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1` should have extension `jar`.

Comment: this is so EMBARRASSING. Thanks to all. @Grzegorz thanks for pointing to my mistake.